# php form create 2 posts

Tags: forms

somebody tried to create a plugin to display a form on the front, wich can add post . To fill it, user must create an account or login. When he create his account, he have to fill 2 field only for the database (not displayed in the backend).
When the form is submitted, it create a new post. But the problem is it create it twice, not only one. I don't understand why.
Could you help me ?
This is the code :

```
public function write_your_story_form() {


  if(is_user_logged_in() === false){
    echo do_shortcode('[theme-my-login]');
  }
  if(is_user_logged_in() === true) {
    global $current_user;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $initial_elle = get_user_meta($user_id, 'lk_initial_elle', true);
    $initial_lui = get_user_meta($user_id, 'lk_initial_lui', true);

    $content = '';
    $initial_ecriture = '';
    //Traitement du formulaire
    if(!empty($_POST['content']) && 
check_admin_referer('ajout_lettre_'.$user_id, 'champ-securite')) {
        $erreur = '';

        //Récupérer les champs obligatoires
        $content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['content']);
        $initial_ecriture = sanitize_text_field($_POST['initial_ecriture']);

         $post_id= wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_content_filtered' => $initial_ecriture,
        'post_title' => $letter_title,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' => 'closed',
            ), true);


        if($post_id = 0){
            $erreur .= 'Erreur technique lors de l\'enregistrement de la lettre. ';
        } else {

                //Envoi de l'e-mail
                /*if(!empty($this->options['email-moderation'])){
                    $body = 'Une histoire a été postée .<br />
                    Vous pouvez la publier en vous rendant dans <a 
href="'.get_admin_url(null, 'edit.php?post_type=oda_annonce').'">votre 
interface d\'administration</a>';
                    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF- 8');
                    wp_mail($this->options['email-moderation'], 'Une annonce 
a été postée', $body, $headers );
                }*/

                //Message de confirmation
                return '<div class="message-confirm"><h2>Demande envoyée</h2><p>Merci d\'avoir envoyer votre lettre. Celle-ci sera publiée après modération<br />Merci de votre compréhension.</p></div>';
        }
  }

ob_start();
?>

<h2>Écrire votre histoire</h2>
<?php if(!empty($erreur)){ ?>
        <p class="message-erreur"><?php echo $erreur; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
<form class="write-your-story-form" action="" method="post">
  <?php wp_nonce_field('ajout_lettre_'.$current_user->ID, 'champ-securite'); ?>
  <label for="content">Écrire votre lettre</label>
  <textarea id="content" name="content" required></textarea>
  <label for="initial_ecriture">Écrire en tant que :</label>
  <select id="initial_ecriture" name="initial_ecriture"required>
    <option value="<?php echo $initial_elle ?>"><?php echo $initial_elle ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $initial_lui ?>"><?php echo $initial_lui ?></option>
  </select>
  <input name="submit" id="submit" value="Envoyer ma lettre" type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $html;
  }
}
```

initial_il and initial_elle are only value for custom field in the database, these values are variables for an other script.
I tried with only one but the result is the same.

Thanks a lot for your help !